# Show that if $U$ and $V$ are ideals in ring $(P, +, \cdot)$ then also $U\cap V$ is ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that if $U$ and $V$ are ideals in ring $(P, +, \cdot)$ then also $U\cap V$ is ideal in $(P, +, \cdot)$ and $U+V= \left \{ u+v: u\in U, v\in V \right \}$ is an ideal in $(P, +, \cdot)$

Completely don't know how to bite that. Any clues would be very helpful.

Comment: There is no trick. Just write down what it means to be an ideal, and check that those sets satisfy those conditions (using that $U$ and $V$ do).

Comment: Ok, so for the intersection will it be: $x\in U\cap V \wedge a\in P \Rightarrow x\in U \wedge ax\in U \wedge x\in V \wedge ax\ V \Rightarrow ax\in U\cap V$ ?

Comment: Yes, though I would probably write it in words rather than so many symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$U\cap V$ will be an ideal because for $w\in U\cap V$ we know both $wx \in U$ and $wx\in V$ for all $x\in P$ since $U$ and $V$ are ideals.
For $U+V$ keep in mind the distributive property of a ring: $(u+v)x = ux + vx$.

Answer (score 1):

Just like probably one half of the questions on this site, the only hint that you should need is:

**Follow the definition!!!**

You need to prove $U\cup V$ is an ideal. Well, by definition, what must be true in order for it to be an ideal? You open your notes, textbook or whatever, and you find, somewhere, something like:

> A subset $I$ of a ring $R$ is an ideal if:
>
> 1. For all elements $x,y\in I$, the element $x+y$ is also in $I$
> 2. For all elements $x\in I$ and $a\in R$, the element $ax$ is also in $I$.

Then, you set about proving both points:

1. You take an arbitrary $x,y\in I$ and you show that $x+y\in I$
2. You take an arbitrary $x\in I$ and an arbitrary $a\in R$, and you show that $ax\in I$.